# No data is displayed in "Chart"

Tags: c#, bar-chart

I am trying to display the column "сoach" from the DB, and display their ranking according to the values in the column "total". As a result I have an empty "Chart"

```
private void fillshar()
{
    conn.Open();
    string selectQuery = "SELECT сoach,total FROM groupfit";
    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
    NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    conn.Close();

    chartRate.Series["total"].XValueMember = "сoach";
    chartRate.Series["total"].YValueMembers = "total";
    chartRate.Titles.Add("Rating of the most popular trainers");
}
```

[image: Result]

[image: Item settings.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `DataTable table = new DataTable();` but you don't change the source of the chart itself...

Try calling `chartRate.DataSource = table;`

Comment: Forgive my carelessness. I am very grateful to you, thank you.